# RIA Services in GAC

Tags: silverlight, ria

I am trying to install the RIA services within the GAC on my server by running the following command line:

msiexec /i RiaServices.msi SERVER=TRUE

The problem i have is that i keep getting an error message saying "The Installation Package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid windows installer package

Can anyone help with this

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this by changing the execution so it reads from a drive

- msiexec /i C:/RiaServices.msi SERVER=TRUE